# how to Sanitize a csv file having errors in headers and data?

Tags: php, python, csv

I download csv files from different places and sometimes the there are special characters like comma, ampersand, etc in the headers and also the data.

Once i receive the file, i get the headers checked and only if the count is matching to the one i have mapped in my system, only then my system accepts the file.

Because of the special characters coming in the file(headers and data), the columns get split and i get wrong info

how can i solve the same using Python or PHP

thanks

Comment: Please show your data, special cases, intended results, and what you've tried.

Comment: i have 5 headers as below

header1, header2, header3, header4, header,5

now if you check the header,5 this is the issue, as a (comma) is inserted which can come in header3 at times and can come in header1 at times, so how do i identify the same and resolve it is my problem.

thanks